# Global splash screen disabler

Tags: windows

I don't like splash screens. If I never saw one, it'd be too soon. Is there a way to make it so that no software ever has a splashscreen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible as splash screens are just like any other window internally and i don't think can be disabled completely however the app ma give the option to disable it! moreover a splash screen is very important as it is the time when resources are loaded so if the splash screen is somehow disabled then what will happen is you start an app nothing happens for 4-5 secs depending on the app then the app starts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "splash screen is somehow disabled then what will happen is you start an app nothing happens for 4-5 secs depending on the app then the app starts" I am undeterred.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution.  The following will remove splash screens from LibreOffice applications (and only LibreOffice applications):

Method A:

1. Open your LibreOffice application folder.
2. Open the `program` sub folder within that folder.
3. Locate the file `soffice.ini`.
4. Open `soffice.ini` and change `Logo=1` to `Logo=0`.

Method B:

1. Append `-nologo` to the command line of all OS shortcuts that point to a LibreOffice application.

Some other applications offer similar flexibility, but the steps required vary per application.